# Is there a more effective way of adding identical views to a UICollectionViewCell without manually specifying each one?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

```
class ListCell: UICollectionViewCell {

let snapshotTitle: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.attributes(text: "Title", textColor: .white, alignment: .left, font: Fonts.rubikMedium, size: 15, characterSpacing: -0.05, backgroundColor: nil)
    return label
}()

let snapshotOne: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.attributes(text: "Item 1", textColor: Colors.appDarkGrey, alignment: .left, font: Fonts.rubikRegular, size: 12, characterSpacing: -0.04, backgroundColor: nil)
    return label
}()

let snapshotTwo: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.attributes(text: "Item 2", textColor: Colors.appDarkGrey, alignment: .left, font: Fonts.rubikRegular, size: 12, characterSpacing: -0.04, backgroundColor: nil)
    return label
}()

let snapshotThree: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.attributes(text: "Item 3", textColor: Colors.appDarkGrey, alignment: .left, font: Fonts.rubikRegular, size: 12, characterSpacing: -0.04, backgroundColor: nil)
    return label
}()

let snapshotFour: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.attributes(text: "Item 4", textColor: Colors.appDarkGrey, alignment: .left, font: Fonts.rubikRegular, size: 12, characterSpacing: -0.04, backgroundColor: nil)
    return label
}()

let snapshotContainer: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 12
    return view
}()

let snapshotGradientBackground: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "itemCellBackgroundPink")
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 12
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    return imageView
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    contentView.addSubview(snapshotGradientBackground)
    snapshotGradientBackground.setAnchors(top: contentView.topAnchor, paddingTop: 0, bottom: contentView.bottomAnchor, paddingBottom: 0, left: contentView.leftAnchor, paddingLeft: 0, right: contentView.rightAnchor, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)

    contentView.addSubview(snapshotContainer)
    snapshotContainer.setAnchors(top: contentView.topAnchor, paddingTop: 45, bottom: contentView.bottomAnchor, paddingBottom: 0, left: contentView.leftAnchor, paddingLeft: 0, right: contentView.rightAnchor, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)

    contentView.addSubview(snapshotTitle)
    snapshotTitle.setAnchors(top: contentView.topAnchor, paddingTop: 0, bottom: snapshotContainer.topAnchor, paddingBottom: 0, left: contentView.leftAnchor, paddingLeft: 12, right: contentView.rightAnchor, paddingRight: 12, width: 0, height: 0)

    contentView.addSubview(snapshotOne)
    snapshotOne.setAnchors(top: snapshotContainer.topAnchor, paddingTop: 18, bottom: nil, paddingBottom: 0, left: snapshotContainer.leftAnchor, paddingLeft: 12, right: snapshotContainer.rightAnchor, paddingRight: 12, width: 0, height: 14)

    contentView.addSubview(snapshotTwo)
    snapshotTwo.setAnchors(top: snapshotOne.bottomAnchor, paddingTop: 14, bottom: nil, paddingBottom: 0, left: snapshotContainer.leftAnchor, paddingLeft: 12, right: snapshotContainer.rightAnchor, paddingRight: 12, width: 0, height: 14)

    contentView.addSubview(snapshotThree)
    snapshotThree.setAnchors(top: snapshotTwo.bottomAnchor, paddingTop: 14, bottom: nil, paddingBottom: 0, left: snapshotContainer.leftAnchor, paddingLeft: 12, right: snapshotContainer.rightAnchor, paddingRight: 12, width: 0, height: 14)

    contentView.addSubview(snapshotFour)
    snapshotFour.setAnchors(top: snapshotThree.bottomAnchor, paddingTop: 14, bottom: nil, paddingBottom: 0, left: snapshotContainer.leftAnchor, paddingLeft: 12, right: snapshotContainer.rightAnchor, paddingRight: 12, width: 0, height: 14)

}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

- I am using a completely programmatic approach to this app
- To help understand this code better, I used extensions for UILabel and UIView:
- ".attributes" specifies text, text color, text alignment, font, text size, and background color
- ".setAnchors" specifies autolayout constraints

Instead of adding each of these labels (snapshotOne, snapshotTwo, snapshotThree, snapshotFour) manually, how would I iterate over a list of items and set the label to that item? Currently, I am just creating separate closures for each item and then adding them in one by one. If it helps, the maximum amount of items I want to show is four (first four items in the list of items).

Here is an image to show what the current code does:

[image]

This is a huge question that I have, and any help is very much appreciated. I am fairly new to Swift programming, so feel free to point out any other concerns in my code if you see any. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the 4 snapshot labels, you can put them in an array:

```
let snapshotLabels = (1...4).map { number in
    let label = UILabel()
    label.attributes(text: "Item \(number)", // note the use of "number" here 
                    textColor: Colors.appDarkGrey, 
                    alignment: .left, 
                    font: Fonts.rubikRegular, 
                    size: 12, 
                    characterSpacing: -0.04, 
                    backgroundColor: nil)
    return label
}
```

For the layout, you could use a [`UIStackView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview) or a `UITableView`, depending on how you want it to look when the number of items is fewer than 4.

With `UIStackView`, you could do

```
let stackView = UIStackView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
stackView.setAnchors(...)
stackView.axis = .vertical
stackView.alignment = .leading
stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
for label in snapshotLabels {
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
}
```